# Extension in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

**I am still learning about extensions, and here is a study case and I don't understand the "return mapOf()"**

```
fun main() {
  val kotlin = "Kotlin".getFirstAndLast()
  val amazing= "Amazing".getFirstAndLast()

  val kotlinFirstChar = kotlin["first"]
  val kotlinLastChar = kotlin["last"]

  val amazingFirstChar = amazing["first"]
  val amazingLastChar = amazing["last"]

  println("First char Kotlin is $kotlinFirstChar and $kotlinLastChar for second letter")
  println("First char Amazing is $amazingFirstChar and $amazingLastChar for second letter")

}
// TODO
fun String.getFirstAndLast(): Map<String, Char>{

    return mapOf()
}
```

Expecting result :

```
First char Kotlin is K and n for second letter
First char Amazing is A and g for second letter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably think you want to get your hands dirty with [destructing declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) and [Pair](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/).

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val (kotlinFirstChar, kotlinLastChar) = "Kotlin".getFirstAndLast()
  val (amazingFirstChar, amazingLastChar) = "Amazing".getFirstAndLast()

  println("First char Kotlin is $kotlinFirstChar and $kotlinLastChar for second letter")
  println("First char Amazing is $amazingFirstChar and $amazingLastChar for second letter")
}

fun String.getFirstAndLast(): Pair<Char, Char> = first() to last()
```

While you can also do this with the help of map as well.

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val kotlin = "Kotlin".getFirstAndLast()
  val amazing= "Amazing".getFirstAndLast()

  val kotlinFirstChar = kotlin["first"]
  val kotlinLastChar = kotlin["last"]

  val amazingFirstChar = amazing["first"]
  val amazingLastChar = amazing["last"]

  println("First char Kotlin is $kotlinFirstChar and $kotlinLastChar for second letter")
  println("First char Amazing is $amazingFirstChar and $amazingLastChar for second letter")
}

fun String.getFirstAndLast(): Map<String, Char> =
    mapOf("first" to first(), "last" to last())
```

Comment: why "first() to last()" with parentheses?

Comment: @tsyanuri what do you mean by parentheses there? (if you are new to Kotlin, then `= X` is same as `{ return X }`)

Comment: never mind, I just realized and understand now. thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, `mapOf` is a utility function in the kolin.collections package.  It returns a new immutable map.

e.g. `val map = mapOf(1 to "one", 2 to "two", 3 to "three")`

Here, 1, 2 and 3 are the keys while one, two and three are the respective values.

If you can mention what language you are comfortable with, we can create an analogy with that language.